# Double For-Next with blanks

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have this code that if the cell turns out to be blank, it would move from `i=1` to `i=2` and essentially resetting the j variable but then I realized the looping for the `i` variable continues even after 10. My question: Is there a way to make it move to the next `i` variable while resetting the `j` variable? I noticed for the `j` variable to end, there has to be a non-zero value at the last cell.

```
For i = 1 to 10
    For j = 9 To 29 Step 2
        If wkst.Cells(i, j) = "" Then
            i=i+1
            j=9
        Else
        End If
        Dest.Cells(i, j) = wkst.Cells(i, j) - wkst.Cells(i, j - 2)
    Next i
Next j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an `Exit For` like this:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 9 To 29 Step 2
        If wkst.Cells(i, j) = "" Then Exit For
        Dest.Cells(i, j) = wkst.Cells(i, j) - wkst.Cells(i, j - 2)
    Next j
Next i
```

Above code will exit the `For Next Loop` for `j` when a blank cell is encountered.
 
Also variables auto increment in a `For Next Loop` so you don't need that part. 
Is this what you're trying? HTH.

Comment: oh ok, so it ends the    j. and thanks, I was trying to figure it out

Comment: Thanks, I'll back track my other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

replace `[next i]` with `[next j]`.

`j` is nested within the i loop so you can't "next" `j` outside it's nesting.